# Can we force Python/Pandas to flush to disk immediately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, subprocess

I have a setup where a python script (let's call it `test1.py`) is spawning a subprocess which executes `test2.py`. In `test2.py`, I have some pandas operations which ultimately builds a dataframe `test`. The final step in `test2.py` is saving the dataframe to csv (`test.to_csv('my_path')`). On completion of `test2.py`, `test1.py` continues execution and the next step required is to load the same csv file created (i.e., `test = pd.read_csv('my_path')`).

Now, the issue is that Python is not flushing the buffer to disk, and therefore, when `test1.py` goes to read the csv file, I get a `FileNotFoundError`. Of course, if I stop the script, the file is saved to disk. Is there a way to force pandas to flush to disk immediately? I've read about using `file.flush()` and `os.fsync(fd)` - but this don't seem to apply to my case since I'm not dealing with any file descriptors.

*EDIT*: Added a (significantly) simplified example

`test1.py` looks something like:

```
import subprocess


def main():
    cmd = ['python3', 'test2.py']
    output_bytes = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, timeout=900)
    output = output_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    # test2.py finished, so I want to read the csv
    df = pd.read_csv('my_path')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`test2.py` looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    df.to_csv('my_path')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please show the relevant (but minimzed) code used in test2 and test1.

Comment: @9769953 - right - edited my question

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue, given the example code. If Daweo's suggestion doesn't solve your problem, it may be an OS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but this don't seem to apply to my case since I'm not dealing with any
> file descriptors.

You do not have to use filename as 1st argument for `.to_csv`, as [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) says you might use

> file-like object implementing a write() function.

therefore you can do something like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3]})
f = open("file.csv","w",newline="")
df.to_csv(f)
f.flush()
f.close()
```

Observe that if you open file in non-binary mode, then you need to disengage universal newlines.

Comment: `close()` always forces a `flush()`; there's no reason to do both separately. What it _doesn't_ do is force a `fsync()`.